# "Non whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements "

Tags: xml, xml-validation

I have an XML File provided by client

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<PhysicalProperty xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation=''>
    <Property>
        <Identification type="unspecified" rentalType="unspecified">
            <PrimaryID>1</PrimaryID>
            <SecondaryID>1</SecondaryID>
            <MarketingName>tewraewr</MarketingName>
            <OwnerLegalName>aerwerwe</OwnerLegalName>
       </Identification>
    </Property>
    </PhysicalProperty>
```

It used to work fine. However now it gives error

"Non whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements. Saw 'tewraewr'"

If I remove attributes in PhysicalProperty, it works fine. How can I make it work without removing the attributes?

Comment: My guess from the message would be that it's complaining about the schema, not about the instance. But I would have expected any decent processor to give some information about the location of the error. Have you doctored the data for publication? Is there actually a schema? Is there more information in the message?

Comment: You are right. The problem is with schema. noNamespaceSchemaLocation attribute does not allow blank values.

Comment: I put some dummy value and it worked.

Comment: I generated dummy values since I am not allowed to share actual data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not an XML expert, but if I had to guess I would think it's your empty '' in the second attribute of your PhysicalProperty element.

Try removing the xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation='' and see if that works.

Comment: You are probably right about the empty schema location, but removing it is not an option according to the OP.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did a similiar thing i.e. put some dummy values as blanks were not an option.